# Unexpected symbol `=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am getting the above error for the following code:

```
public class Sheep : Animal {
    //hpMax = 100;
    //power = 10;
    //defense = 10;
    //speed = 10;
    animalName = "Sheep Test";

    public override void Attack()
    {
        Debug.Log(animalName);
    }

}
```

It appears that I can't assign variables outside of a method.  Is this the case?  That would mean I'd have to create a "AssignStats()" method to assign HPMax, power, defense, speed, etc.  I think it's probably clear why I want to avoid adding this added step to the code every time I call an animal object.

Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: `String animalName = "Sheep Test";`. You always need to specify a type for member variables.

Comment: Yes, you are missing something obvious. You are declaring the member `animalName` without specifying a type.

Comment: @Mephy Ridiculous. Thank you so much.  I thought that since it inherited animalName I didn't need to do that. So so obvious.  So sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a type declaration for your `animalName` attribute.

If `animalName` is declared in the base class as a protected variable you could set the `animalName` in the constructor like this:

```
public Sheep() : base(){
   animalName = "Sheep Test";
}
```

This assumes that the `Animal` class is defined similar to this:

```
public class Animal{
   protected string animalName;  //protected allows descendent classes 
                                 //direct access to the var.
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I am getting downvotes, I assume, because of how simple this answer was but I have legitimately been working on this forever.

Comment: the down votes seem punitive, if you are learning then I think it's a perfectly legit question.

Comment: @T McKeown: Actually, the problem that lead me to first remove the string identifier is back. The following does not print anything at all.  The debug.log function is displaying nothing at all.

public class Sheep : Animal {
    string animalName = "Sheep Test";

    public override void Attack()
    {
        Debug.Log(animalName);
    }

}